# CheckBox click in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, android-checkbox

I have a listview with some text and a checkbox. I can click the checkbox, and the check changes, but when I try to listen for the check being changed, or the click, the listener never triggers.

I have the listview in an Activity (not a ListActivity)

schedule.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/schedulerLayout">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/currentHours"
                android:textSize="50dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:text=":"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/currentMinutes"
                android:textSize="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--vertical filler for am/pm display -->
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ampm"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/currentDayOfWeek"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/currentDate"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scheduleButton"
        android:text="@string/newSchedule"/>
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/scheduler_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

schedulerow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheduleListTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Title"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheduleListDays"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scheduleListTitle"
        android:text="Days"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheduleListMonths"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scheduleListDays"
        android:text="Months"/>
<View
        android:id="@+id/schedulerSeparator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@id/scheduleListMonths"/>
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/scheduleCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/schedulerSeparator"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheduleListTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/scheduleCheckBox"
        android:text="Time"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm filling in the data like this:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            data,
            R.layout.schedulerow,
            new String[] {"Title","Time","Day", "Month"},
            new int[] { R.id.scheduleListTitle, R.id.scheduleListTime,R.id.scheduleListDays, R.id.scheduleListMonths});

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If I try to add a listener to the checkbox, it does nothing. Any suggestions? I've looked through a TON of sample code and similar questions, and none of it seems to work.

Comment: You want the item click listener or the check listener to be called..? Where and how do you set the listeners?

Comment: I've tried a bunch of ways... I've tried setting a `CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` and I've tried `CheckBox.setOnClickListener()`. I tried both ways in `OnCreate` for my main activity, as well as after filling the `ListView` with items. I've also tried setting them within the `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView`. I don't know what else to try. All of the other solutions I see look complicated, and aren't well explained.

Comment: Also, the `ItemClickListener` for the `ListView` is working properly. Just not the listeners for the `CheckBox`

Comment: Why do you block focus on the check box..? dont block..

Comment: If I don't block focus on the checkbox, `OnItemClickListener` doesn't work for the `ListView`

Comment: "you set the checkchange listner in getView of adapter.." - how? I've seen a million examples, but all of them assume that I'm using `ListActivity` and not `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to forget the list item click listener and use another listener for the rest of the item other than the checkbox.. In item layout xml, put the other views in single layout and set the click listener on this and set the check listener on checkbox as usual. Both will work without issues. Dont use the list item click listener.

```
class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
 ... 
   @Override
   void getView(.....) {
       View view = super.getView(.....);
       view.findViewById(R.id.checkboxid).setOnCheckChangedListner(checklistener);
       view.findViewById(R.id.restOfitemview).setOnClickListner(clickListner);
       return view;
    }
}
```

Define the two listeners and set as shown above.

Edit : First try your method(blocking focus on checkbox) with the `MySimpleAdapter` setting only the checkchangelistener.. If that does not work then use above solution of dividing the item layout.

Comment: Thank you SO much! I kept the `OnItemClickListener` the way that I had it, and added the `OnCheckChangedListener` here. Works well! Thanks again!

Comment: Excewt that in order for it to work properly, I had to use `OnClickListener`. If I use `OnCheckChangedListener`, it was triggered when I clicked a `ListView` item, and it toggled uncontrollably. I did get that figured out too though.